# Can't see individual test results in a list in the VS2019 Test Explorer when using TestCaseSource

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit, test-explorer

I am doing a kind of integration test - I am testing for HTTP 200 with some REST API endpoints . Anyway, that is not important for my question.

This is my test:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using NUnit.Framework.Internal;

namespace EndpointTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Tests
    {
        public class EndPoint
        {
            // just a container for URL, bearer token and so on
        }

        private static IEnumerable<EndPoint> EndPoints()
        {
            // this function returns a list of test data objects, about 150 pcs
        }

        [Test]
        [TestCaseSource(typeof(EndpointTests.Tests), nameof(EndPoints))]
        public async Task Should_Respond_Http200OK_When_Requested(EndPoint endPoint)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual( ... );
        }
    }
}
```

I have an `IEnumerable` list of about 150 objects which in turn contains data that I use to feed my test function (more correctly: it's my `TestCaseSource`). I know that Visual Studio is running all 150 tests correctly, just as expected. The problem is that I can't see individual results.

## My question

Is it possible to have Visual Studio to print each individual test result in a list in the Test Explorer?
Like this?
[image: This is what I want to achieve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your test definition, NUnit will create a test suite called `Should_Respond_Http200OK_When_Requested` containing 150 tests cases. The test cases will all have the same name, not visible in your attachment but probably something like `Should_Respond_Http200OK_When_Requested(<EndPoint>)`.

NUnit itself has no problem with 150 test cases with the same name. It has other ways to identify tests. TestExplorer, however, uses the name to distinguish tests. It treats this situation as a single test having 150 results. Those results should be visible when you highlight the test, but it's not a very convenient display.

When creating a test name, NUnit uses the string representation of each argument. If you give your `EndPoint` class a `ToString()` override, then NUnit will use that for the display. Provided the representation is unique, TestExplorer will recognize these as distinct tests.